How to generate when-then constructs in polars dynamically?
I am working with polars expressions as below.
pl.when(pl.col(a).contains("some value")).then(pl.concat_list("ArayColumn"),[A])
  .when(pl.col(a).contains("some value")).then(pl.concat_list("ArayColumn"),[B])
  .when(pl.col(a).contains("some value")).then(pl.concat_list("ArayColumn"),[C])
  .otherwise("Z is Big").alias("Bigger Value")

However, I'd like to generate these expressions dynamically (as in the following pseudo-code).
exprs = []
for i,value on conditions: 
  exprs.append(pl.when(i).then(value))

exprs.otherwise(defaultValue).alias("Bigger Value")

Then, I'd like to evaluate exprs in the context of a dataframe.
df.with_columns(exprs)

So, i want for each row, it should first when, then, second when, then.....
i should evaluate every when.then condition and union all
my final values may contain [A, B, C].
Tried Approaches :

For Loop and applying one by one , but if dataFrame has huge data its blasting.
Expression chaining , but polars otherwise is taking None by default for every conditions i kept and making it slow [ few ms ]

can you suggest me any other approach ? I need to generate the expression and later i will apply on dataFrame.

Could you provide a runnable example (including an example dataframe along with the expected output)?

You can also use pl.coalesce. For example pl.when(cond).then(result).when(cond_2).then(result_2)
becomes pl.coalesce(pl.when(cond).then(result), pl.when(cond_2).then(result_2)).
This makes the expression a little easier to build dynamically and saves the potentially confusing expr = pl initialisation. coalesce also operates in parallel like when/then, so performance should be similar. fill_null can be used in place of otherwise to provide a default value.
df = pl.DataFrame({"string": ["1", "foo bar", "bar", "baz", "quux"]})

conditions = {"foo": "contains foo", "bar": "contains bar", "baz": "contains baz"}

expr = pl.coalesce(
    pl.when(pl.col("string").str.contains(key)).then(pl.lit(value))
    for key, value in conditions.items()
)

df.with_columns(output=expr.fill_null(pl.lit("other")))

┌─────────┬──────────────┐
│ string  ┆ output       │
│ ---     ┆ ---          │
│ str     ┆ str          │
╞═════════╪══════════════╡
│ 1       ┆ other        │
│ foo bar ┆ contains foo │
│ bar     ┆ contains bar │
│ baz     ┆ contains baz │
│ quux    ┆ other        │
└─────────┴──────────────┘


You can dynamically create a chain of .when/.then like this:
First do expr = pl, then in each for loop, do expr = expr.when(_).then(_).
After the loop, do a select or with_columns for expr.otherwise(_).
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "string": ["1", "foo bar", "bar", "baz", "quux"],
    }
)

conditions = {"foo": "contains foo", "bar": "contains bar", "baz": "contains baz"}

expr = pl

for key, value in conditions.items():
    expr = expr.when(pl.col("string").str.contains(key)).then(pl.lit(value))

df = df.with_columns(output=expr.otherwise(pl.lit("other")))

print(df)

Output:
┌─────────┬──────────────┐
│ string  ┆ output       │
│ ---     ┆ ---          │
│ str     ┆ str          │
╞═════════╪══════════════╡
│ 1       ┆ other        │
│ foo bar ┆ contains foo │
│ bar     ┆ contains bar │
│ baz     ┆ contains baz │
│ quux    ┆ other        │
└─────────┴──────────────┘


Above will generate expression like this :
.when(col("Array").is_null()).then(Series[literal]).otherwise(.when(col("cond").python_udf()).then(col("Array").list.concat([Series[literal]])).otherwise(.when(col("cond").python_udf()).then(col("array").list.concat([Series[literal]])).otherwise(.when(col("cond").python_udf()).then(col("array").list.concat([Series[literal]])).otherwise(col("array"))))).alias("ArrayName")
So, if one condition matches rest of the conditions will be ignored.
Next condition is going inside of the otherwise.

in Polars , Otherwise will be added by default if we don't specify

@Sampat did you see the output I posted? It looks correct to me. The 3rd row ("bar") gets the output "contains bar".

For "foo bar" , can we get output as [Contains foo , contains bar] because it has both foo, bar.

@Sampat You can with a single concat_list and multiple when/thens. You should edit your question to include a sample dataframe along with the exact expected output. This allows people to give a first time answer without any ambiguity.
